# Add a product into a custom page - Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

All is in the question, is it possible to add a product into a page that i created ?

Do i have to build some controllers etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to show PrestaShop products on a custom page. You first have to create a front controller through a module as follows.

You need to create a separate controller for that in your module at the following path:

/modules/supercheckout/controllers/front/fcont.php (where supercheckout is your module name)

and write the following code in the file:

```
class SupercheckoutFcontModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

public function initContent()
{
        parent::initContent();
        $this->setTemplate('template_file.tpl');
}
}
```

And then include the product-list.tpl file of the theme in the template file of your module to list products in on your controller page.

```
{include file="$tpl_dir./product-list.tpl" products=$filtered_products id='block_list_id'}
```

Note: The $filtered_products variable contains the products that are to be loaded on the custom controller page.

Comment: could you just explain why do i have to pass by a module?